# Angular popover autoclose property - open only 1 popover at a time

Tags: angular, popover, auto-close

I have a list of contacts and for each contact i can add a note.
My requirement is- If i open notes popover for 1 contact and then click on 'Add notes' of second contact then only 2nd popover should be open and not both.

I tried to set [autoClose]="'outside'", but then I am not able to apply styles from dropdown menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQ7Y.png)
(I am using tinymce editor)

```
 <a triggers="manual" #notesBox="ngbPopover" [ngbPopover]="notesEditor" [autoClose]="'outside'" popoverTitle='My Note'(click)="notesBox.open()">
```

Can anyone suggest the solution please

Comment: about what popover are you talking about? ng bootstrap popover? Please, specify and include a complete code snippet of what you're trying.

Comment: yes .. ngbpopver @ChrisTapay

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.0, the [ngbPopover](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api) closes on both outside and inside clicks as well as Escape presses. Remove the `autoClose` input from your example so the popover will use the default behavior (autoClose = true)

Since you're using a manual trigger, make sure to use the proper template references and logic to open/close your modal. Refer to the [manual triggers example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#tplwithcontext) to check that out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ChrisTapay ... I have tried with defualt value to autoClose property.. and toggle works fine with it. But problem is even if i click on menubar of my notes editor, it closes the pop over. ( Added the screen shot my menu in question above)

Comment: Please, elaborate better on what the issue is. From your last edit, it seems to be the issue is not what the title says but that you're not able to apply styles from tinymce editor because the popover is getting closed? Set a working example in order to help. Thanks.